# Ошибка при создании базы данных

Tags: python, sqlite

Начал изучать создания баз данных в python.
Написал код для создание бд как в документации, но почему то возникает ошибка.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\bot_zadach\test.py", line 6, in <module>
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "1za"
```

Не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться в чем тут дело.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('orders.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   fullname TEXT,
   1za TEXT,
   1za_pom INT,
   2za TEXT,
   2za_pom INT,
   3za TEXT,
   3za_pom INT.
   4za TEXT,
   4za_pom INT,
   5za TEXT,
   5za_pom INT,
   6za TEXT,
   6za_pom INT,
   7za TEXT,
   7za_pom INT,
   8za TEXT,
   8za_pom INT.
   9za TEXT,
   9za_pom INT,
   10za TEXT,
   10za_pom INT);
""")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Скорее всего, тут правило именования как и у переменных в коде -- не может начинаться с цифры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Название колонок должны быть в кавычках

Т.е вот так

```py
sql = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
   "id" INT PRIMARY KEY,
   "fullname" TEXT,
   "1za" TEXT,
   "1za_pom" INTEGER,
   "2za" TEXT,
   "2za_pom" INTEGER,
   "3za" TEXT
);
"""
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @данила соловьев, поставь решение, пж